# table-footer-group and safari / chrome / mobile

Tags: css, mobile

so I have containers set up like so:

```
<div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

The left div is the login, the right div is the content...

With media queries, when the browser gets small enough I want the left(login) section to go on the bottom of the right(content) div.

I tried using table-header-group on the .right div and table-footer-group on the .left, and it works on the desktop browser perfectly in FF...however in chrome, safari and IE...including iphone and android phone it doesnt work at all.

My entire layout is based around needing this first div to be below the second one for the mobile layout...is this possible at all or do I have to redo the entire structure of the site?

ex. http://jsfiddle.net/VF6Hy/1/

EDIT: If this is not possible with pure css, would there be a JS option to stack the second div above the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda worked around the issue by adding a large min-height to the container and position:absolute to the .right div and bottom:0 on the mobile version which put it on the bottom